# Salesforce not working with HTMLUnit

Tags: java, web-scraping, salesforce, htmlunit

I'm trying to use HTMLUnit to do some web-scraping on Salesforce, to get the organization licenses info. It works if I try using accessing Salesforce through the regular login/test url. But I want to be able to login via session id using the /secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid= method.

When I try to use that, Salesforce complains that javascript is not enabled. But I have it enabled in HTMLUnit.

```
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
        HtmlPage page;

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(true);

        page = webClient.getPage("https://salesforce--domain/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=SessionId");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For some reason, your not getting automatically redirected. So you just need to get the URL from the first getPage and go to the new new URL.

```
     java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
    HtmlPage page;

    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(true);

    page = webClient.getPage("https://salesforce--domain/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=SessionId");
```

page = webClient.getPage(page.getURL());